# Minecraft Play from 2 different computers in the same house

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My grandson loves Minecraft and I would like to become more familiar with it and play against him. He plays upstairs on his computer and I use the computer downstairs. How can we play against one another? Let's make this an easy fix, please.

Comment: 2 copies of Minecraft, create a Lan server. should be pretty simple, just don't recall the exact steps. something along the lines of load a world, go to the menu, select Lan Server. then have yourself or your son go into multiplayer and type in the IP address

Answer (score 18):

First you will need to purchase a second Minecraft account to play with and install Minecraft on your downstairs computer.

Once you've got Minecraft and you can log in, one of you can open a world and press `ESC` to bring up the menu:

[image: Screenshot of the Game Menu reached by pausing the game]

Click the <kbd>Open to LAN</kbd> option. A new screen will come up allowing you to select the game options you want to use, and then select <kbd>Start LAN World</kbd> to open the LAN server.

The other player should be able to connect at the bottom of the list on the Multiplayer screen:

[image: A slice of screenshot of the multiplayer connection menu]

Answer (score 1):

Alright took a minute to do this.

Have yourself or your son create a world. Enter that world, moment you enter hit "esc" should see a button "Open to LAN" click it. Will give you a couple toggle options, click "Start LAN world" will load for a second then give you an IP address that you may or may not need.

Next have the other person go into Multiplayer should automatically start scanning for local games, meaning the game you just opened to LAN. Once you see the server appear just join it. If it doesn't show up just go to "Direct Connect" and type in the IP address that your game gave you previously.

Pretty sure you need 2 copies of Minecraft for this.

Comment: You do need two accounts.