# Can a player on a PC play Minecraft with a player on a laptop?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play Minecraft on my PC, but my son wants a laptop. Can he join me in my world? Can PC's/laptop's play together? We both play together on MCPE, but I prefer PC.

Comment: Technically "PC" is a desktop computer and "laptop" is a portable computer. Both usually have the same capabilities.

Comment: As long as the "laptop" is not a Chromebook or something weird like a Pi Top. Actually, both of those can probably play Minecraft but it will quickly get more complicated than you might like.

Comment: Laptops *are* PCs. They just have a different shape from desktops.

Comment: @immibis Well, laptop *might* be a PC (which usually refers to what has descended from IBM PC and compatibles, and today can run Windows OOTB). Apple's laptops or Google Chromebooks aren't usually referred to as "PC".

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this question holds any value to the site considering it lacks a baseline understanding or research of the topic.

Comment: @DoritoStyle I wouldn't be so critical. It's an understandable issue. You can't expect games on all platforms to be compatible with each other, sometimes even between Windows and Mac. We still don't know if OP means they have OS X, Linux or whatever on their laptop *or* PC. Could be anything for all we know. But the meta-answer here could be to go look up cross-play compatibility on wikipedia, steam or forums, which includes asking here if there's no easily available information about that.

Answer (score 28):

Assuming you are both playing the same version of Minecraft, **Yes**.

You will both need separate accounts, as the same MC account (UUID) cannot be in the same world twice. However, you will both need to play the same type of Minecraft as well as have the same version. For example if one of you is playing the Windows 10 Edition and the other the Java version, you won't be able to play together.

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/198177/104387) has information on how to connect.

Comment: Oh come on, you beat me by 38 seconds :)

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek the 'net these days...

Answer (score 9):

#### Yes.

It's as easy as connecting to another player's world in Minecraft PE. One player opens the game to the local network ("LAN") through the ESC menu, the other one connects through the multiplayer list. This is possible because Minecraft for PC and laptop is the same thing.

If you would have any issues, check out this: [Why isn't my Minecraft LAN server working?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/why-isnt-my-minecraft-lan-server-working)

Comment: While **Yes** is indeed the correct answer, I don't believe you answered the question the OP asked. I believe the OP seemed to think that PC  & Laptop count as different consoles, which they do not.

Comment: @Oak PC and Laptop [aren't consoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_console). You probably meant different platforms.

Comment: @user1306322 Indeed, my bad =)

Comment: @Brandy please consider marking this question as accepted by clicking on the gray check mark next to this answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

While the other answers aren't wrong, I believe they answer the wrong question. If I understand this correctly, your issue is with knowing whether or not a **desktop user** can play with a **laptop user**. Most likely the question comes from the fact that Minecraft has an Xbox version that isn't compatible with desktops.

With that taken care of, yes, it is possible to play on a **laptop** with **desktop players**. That is because the computer versions of the game are all compatible with one another (All operating Systems can play with one another).

In sum, yes it's possible to play **desktop/desktop** , **desktop/laptop** and **laptop/laptop**, even if they have different operating Systems (Windows, Mac, Linux, etc..)

Comment: That's... basically what I answered? And also, the PC-Windows 10 connection may need troubleshooting in some cases.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek I think your answer better answers the question as asked.  Oak is trying to respond to the implicit question. Both are good answers.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek To someone who is just a little tech savy it's easy to miss the little things, my answer differs from yours in the aspect that it tries to awnser an issue raised by interpeting the question differently; From what I understood, the question arose due to the OP not knowing that laptops/desktops are equipparable rather than mutually exlusive (like desktops/Console). Like I said in my awnser, I aimed at awnsering what could be a lack of foundations of the OP. Your awnser is still great nevertheless =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your son and you can play together with laptop and PC. Since both are working in same principle regardless the design/hardware shapes. All you need to be sure is, that both platforms are capable of supporting what Minecraft game requires as specs.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, as long as you both are running the same version, you can connect to the same server.

The term PC originally meant PC Compatible, as in IBM PC.  As opposed to Apple Macintosh. [WhatIs.com](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/personal-computer-PC).......I still have some disks laying around that say PC-compatible somewhere

Then it got changed to something that made more sense, Personal Computer, which makes more sense now, seeing as everything can more or less be made to play nice across OS's.

And now it has been co-opted yet again, by who knows what entity, who wants to state that a PC is a system that sits motionless, while a laptop has no classification.....which makes no sense......

Laptops and towers/desktops, are both PCs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Regardless of what OS a laptop or desktop has, as long as the version of Minecraft is the same you're fine. The only case it wouldn't work is if you were trying to do it desktop/laptop with console/PE. As long as your server or realm is working properly there should be no issue.